# Redirect user to page where he was before session expires.(backbone and asp mvc5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, session-timeout

I am using backbone js at front-end to index my pages and asp mvc 5 at back-end.
How should i redirect the user to page where it was before session expired. I was using returnurl but the problem is that the backbone pages are indexed using "#"  and server neglect the address after #. So my application always redirect to homepage.

Comment: Are you redirecting on the backbone side or the asp side? Also keep in mind that you can use the History api with backbone and get real urls.

Comment: I am redirecting on asp side. can i take window.history object on server side when session expires.  And Is there some event for session expiration?